# How the f*&% to stop voice-to-text from censoring profanity?

Tags: input-methods, auto-correct, voice-recognition

The voice-to-text feature is very useful, but every once in a while when sending an SMS or email message to a friend, I want to really let loose.

However, Google, in their defense of my virginal eyes, replaces such words with hashes (####) if it recognizes the word at all.

How do I turn off this ####### "feature"?

Comment: Here's my trouble: it worked on my previous droid razr maxx, but after I got it replaced with another when it got broken, even when I uncheck "block offensive language" or whatever under the voice-text input, it STILL does it.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

There is a checkable/uncheckable option called **Block offensive words** under **Settings** → **Voice input & output** → **Voice recognizer settings**.

In Android 8.1, that setting is in **Settings** → **System** → **Languages & input** → **Virtual keyboard** → **Google voice typing** → **Block offensive words**

For Samsung phones, the settings are named slightly differently: from the **Settings** app, try **Language & input** → **Voice search settings** → **Block offensive words**. This of course **only works with the integrated Google voice recognition**.

You also have to go to the gboard where the virtual keyboard is and also turn off that block for offensive words

For Android 4.3 (and possibly earlier versions):

**Settings** → **Language & input** → **Google voice typing (settings)** → **Block offensive words**

For Samsung S8+: **Settings** → **General management** → **Language and input** → **On screen keyboard** → **Google voice typing** → **Block offensive words**

Answer (score 0):

I have a Moto E on Boost Mobile. It's a little different. `Settings > Language & Input > Google Keyboard > Text Correction` (There is also a setting called Current Keyboard. Make sure to go into Google Keyboard instead.) "Block Offensive Words" switch off, and you can curse like a sailor!

Edit-  That didn't change the censored output, but they're right! There's another one. Settings, Lang. & Input, Google Voice Typing, Block Offensive Words switch. This one made the output change. Wonder what the other one is for?